# Implementing the COREui Admin Template to match the demo

Tags: css, symfony, templates, bootstrap-5

I am learning web development and I am trying to use the COREui 4.0.1 Bootstrap admin template in an existing Symfony 5.3 project instead of standard Bootstrap 5 components and utilities. I am trying to get the page to look like https://coreui.io/demo/free/3.4.0/.

The project was created using `symfony new my_project_name --full`. I added Bootstrap CSS with https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/getting-started/introduction/#css and JS with https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/getting-started/introduction/#bundle to my base.html.twig.

Steps that I took:

- Create a new controller
- Create an associated view using a twig template
- Replaced the Bootstrap JS with https://coreui.io/docs/4.0/getting-started/introduction/#bundle and CSS with https://coreui.io/docs/4.0/getting-started/introduction/#css in my base.html.twig

What I was expecting:

- When accessing the controller/view I would see https://coreui.io/demo/free/3.4.0/

The actual result:

- Minor styling changes (from COREui rather than original Bootstrap) but no layout changes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CoreUI CSS and JS that you have added to your project is to be used in the same way that you would use Bootstrap components and utilities i.e. adding *to* existing HTML elements.

Viewing the page source at the demo you provided at https://coreui.io/demo/free/3.4.0/ shows the HTML elements that you would need to have in your own project, that would then have CoreUI (in this case) CSS and JS components applied *to* them.

Using that demo https://coreui.io/demo/free/3.4.0/, if you wanted a side navigation bar you would need to have a HTML element like:

```
<div class="c-sidebar c-sidebar-dark c-sidebar-fixed c-sidebar-lg-show" id="sidebar">
    <div class="c-sidebar-brand d-lg-down-none">
...
```